# Как загрузить ядро системы загрузчиком на fasm?

Tags: c, ассемблер, kernel, ос, fasm

Доброе время суток! Недавно начал писать свою ос на FASM и C и застрял на создании ядра. (пишу в Windows, mingw)

Вкратце, мне нужно залинковать загрузчик и ядро, но пока ничего не выходит.

#### Код загрузчика (bootloader.asm):

```
format binary
; preparation
org 0x7c00
use16

begin:
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax

mov [disk], dl ; save disk number for later

mov si, loading16 ; print welcome string
pchar:
 .lp:
  mov al, [si]
  cmp al, 0
  je .exit
 .pch:
  mov ah, 0eh
  int 10h
  add si, 1
  jmp .lp
 .exit:


mov ah, 0  ;reset disk
int 13h

; load kernel_entry and kernel from disk
mov ah, 2h     ;read sectors
mov al, 1      ;sectors to read
mov ch, 0      ;cylinder idx
mov dh, 0      ;head idx
mov cl, 2      ;sector idx
mov dl, [disk] ;disk idx
mov bx, 0x1000 ;target pointer
int 13h


; get into pm and jump to KERNEL label
jmp switch_to_pm

jmp $ ; never executed

use32
KERNEL:

jmp 0x1000 ; jump to the actual kernel

jmp $ ; never executed


include './32/gdt.asm'        ; gdt for protected mode
include './32/switch32.asm'   ; code for entering protected mode
include './32/strout32.asm'   ; protected mode print

;; data

disk: rb 1

use16
wc32: db "Welcome to x32!", 0
loading16: db "Loading OS"
osver: db "v.0.0", 0

;bootloader fill
times 510-($-$$) db 0
;magic number
dw 0xaa55

;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

#### ./32/gdt.asm:

```
use16
gdt_start:
    dq 0x0
gdt_code:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_data:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_end:

; GDT descriptor
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; size (16 bit), always one less of its true size
    dd gdt_start ; address (32 bit)

; define some constants for later use
CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

#### ./32/strout32.asm:

```
use32

VIDEO_MEMORY equ 0xb8000
WHITE_ON_BLACK equ 0x0f ; the color byte for each character

__print_string_label:
    mov edx, VIDEO_MEMORY

.print_string_pm_loop:
    mov al, [ebx] ; [ebx] is the address of our character
    mov ah, WHITE_ON_BLACK

    cmp al, 0 ; check if end of string
    je .print_string_pm_done

    mov [edx], ax ; store character + attribute in video memory
    add ebx, 1 ; next char
    add edx, 2 ; next video memory position

    jmp .print_string_pm_loop

.print_string_pm_done:
    ret

;PRINT MACRO
macro print _str* {
      mov ebx, _str
      call __print_string_label
}
```

#### ./32/switch32.asm:

```
use16
switch_to_pm:
    mov ax, 0x2401
    int 15h ;A20

    mov ax, 3h
    int 10h

    cli ; 1. disable interrupts
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor] ; 2. load the GDT descriptor
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1 ; 3. set 32-bit mode bit in cr0
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm ; 4. far jump by using a different segment

use32
init_pm: ; we are now using 32-bit instructions
    mov ax, DATA_SEG ; 5. update the segment registers
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000 ; 6. update the stack right at the top of the free space
    mov esp, ebp

    call KERNEL ; 7. Call a well-known label with useful code
use16 ;
```

#### Код загрузчика ядра (kernelentr.asm):

```
format elf
use32
extrn _start
call _start

jmp $
```

#### Ядро (kernel.c):

```
void start (void) 
{
   unsigned char* vga = (unsigned char*) 0xb8000;
   vga[0] = 'X'; //need to make sure that this is a character
   vga[1] = 0x09; //append the attribute byte
   for(;;); //make sure our kernel never stops, with an infinite loop
}
```

Мой порядок действий:

1. Компиляция ядра

   ```
   gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -nostdlib -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
   ```
2. Линковка получившегося обьекта и загрузчика ядра(?)

   ```
   ld -T NUL -o kernel.tmp -Ttext 0x1000 kernelentr.o kernel.o
   ```
3. Извлечение бинарного кода из ядра с загрузчиком

   ```
   objcopy -O binary -j .text  kernel.tmp kernel.bin
   ```
4. Совмещение загрузчика и получившегося бинарника

   ```
   copy /b bootloader.bin+kernel.bin os.bin
   ```

**EDIT:** Команды брал отсюда - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25128579/ld-cannot-perform-pe-operations-on-non-pe-output-file-error

После всей процедуры получается файл который, увы, не запускается и вылетает из QEMU с ошибкой `'Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0xc6fc458b'`

*Укажите пожалуйста на ошибку и и скажите как все таки заставить это штуку работать.*

**UPDATE**: Вдруг бинарник таки заработал, но криво - 
Теперь при запуске и правда высвечиваеся синяя буква Х, но экран постоянно меняется на до х32 (с надписью `Loading OS v0.0`) и обратно.
При этом эмулятор не крашится...

Comment: Какой "файл запускается" - не нужно никакой файл запускать. Почитайте как происходит процесс загрузки...

Comment: В кратце, 1)ребут,  2)грузится промежуточный загрузчик "партиции" если нет бут-лоадер - идем на шаг 3. Если есть - то же но через б/л. 3)загрузилась bin 512 байт по определённому адресу. Он грузит либо вспомогательный 4, либо сразу 5. 4) загрузчик 4кб (или 512 байт) ищет файл "начального ядра". Находит, линейно грузит в память 5, и передаёт ему управление. 5) 5 состоит из 6+7. 6-загрузчик elf или MZ/PE заголовка. он тупо делает  распаковку, пересвязывание, переключает в защищенный режим, и запускает основное ядро 7. 7.основное ядро.

Comment: Какую часть процесса загрузки вы делаете - не понятно. Точно могу сказать одно, ни один из приведенных пунктов 1-7 без специальной "прокладки" запущен не может быть. п 1- сам стартует при ребуте. Какой "файл запускается" - не нужно никакой файл запускать.

Comment: Ну начальное сообщение он должен выводить. так как делает это до догрузки остальной части. Раз у вас этого не происходит, значит начальный код попал не туда куда нужно. лучше всего посмотреть дизассемблером полученный bin файл и для начала убедится, что нужный стартовый код (там где у вас `begin:`) действительно в самом начале файла и что его ликер или copy не засунули еще куда нибудь.

Comment: @Mike каким то образом я заставил бинарник не крашить эмулятор, но теперь он почему то ведет себя очень странно, постоянно меняется экран до х32 битный с надписью о загрузке с голубым иксом который выводит уже ядро на с

Comment: Ну это похоже на правду. C код выводит свой X, а после же у вас нет никакого кода, он налетает на недопустимую операцию и эмулятор уходит в перезагрузку и все по новой происходит

Comment: Знаете, а я ведь поменял код кернела и забыл, поэтому в конце есть уже бесконечный цикл) for(;;)

Comment: Вообще то там после `call _start` уже есть бесконечный цикл, по идее дополнительно внутри функции цикл не нужен.

Comment: @insolor Да, но вот только qemu не крашится только если бесконечный цикл в С функции прописан

Comment: @Jiftoo, на шаге `ld -T NUL -o kernel.tmp -Ttext 0x1000 kernelentr.o kernel.o` получается псевдоисполняемый файл с 2 исполняемыми секциями: `.flat` и `.text` (в первой находится "загрузчик ядра"). В результате следующей операции извлекается только содержимое секции `.text` (сишный код). Получается, что загрузчик ядра у вас вообще никак не используется.

Comment: @insolor тогда напишите пожалуйста как правильно скомпилировать ядро

Comment: Присмотрелся, не заметил до этого бесконечный `jmp $`. Если он не помогает, а помогает только цикл внутри C-кода, значит `ret` генерируемый в C-коде не соответствует размером тому call которым вызывается. Опять же, поможет только изучение получающегося файла под микроскопом, т.е. дизассемблером

Comment: Зачем вы пишете 32-разрядную систему? На x86 их время прошло лет десять тому назад.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На шаге `ld -T NUL -o kernel.tmp -Ttext 0x1000 kernelentr.o kernel.o` получается файл с двумя исполняемыми секциями: `.flat` ("загрузчик ядра") и `.text` (сишный код):

[image: Скриншот]

```
.flat:00000000 ; Segment type: Pure code
.flat:00000000 ; Segment permissions: Read/Write/Execute
.flat:00000000 _flat           segment dword public 'CODE' use32
.flat:00000000                 assume cs:_flat
.flat:00000000                 assume es:nothing, ss:nothing, ds:_flat, fs:nothing, gs:nothing
.flat:00000000                 call    _start
.flat:00000005
.flat:00000005 loc_5:                                  ; CODE XREF: .flat:loc_5j
.flat:00000005                 jmp     short loc_5
.flat:00000005 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.flat:00000007                 align 200h
.flat:00000200                 dd 380h dup(?)
.flat:00000200 _flat           ends
.flat:00000200
.text:00001000 ; Section 2. (virtual address FFC01000)
.text:00001000 ; Virtual size                  : 00000020 (     32.)
.text:00001000 ; Section size in file          : 00000200 (    512.)
.text:00001000 ; Offset to raw data for section: 00000600
.text:00001000 ; Flags 60300020: Text Executable Readable
.text:00001000 ; Alignment     : 4 bytes
.text:00001000 ; ===========================================================================
.text:00001000
.text:00001000 ; Segment type: Pure code
.text:00001000 ; Segment permissions: Read/Execute
.text:00001000 _text           segment dword public 'CODE' use32
.text:00001000                 assume cs:_text
.text:00001000                 ;org 1000h
.text:00001000                 assume es:nothing, ss:nothing, ds:_flat, fs:nothing, gs:nothing
.text:00001000
.text:00001000 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:00001000
.text:00001000 ; Attributes: bp-based frame
.text:00001000
.text:00001000                 public _start
.text:00001000 _start          proc near               ; CODE XREF: .flat:00000000p
.text:00001000
.text:00001000 var_4           = dword ptr -4
.text:00001000
.text:00001000                 push    ebp
.text:00001001                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:00001003                 sub     esp, 10h
.text:00001006                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0B8000h
.text:0000100D                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
.text:00001010                 mov     byte ptr [eax], 58h ; 'X'
.text:00001013                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
.text:00001016                 add     eax, 1
.text:00001019                 mov     byte ptr [eax], 9
.text:0000101C                 nop
.text:0000101D                 leave
.text:0000101E                 retn
.text:0000101E _start          endp
.text:0000101E
.text:0000101E ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:0000101F                 align 200h
.text:00001200                 dd 380h dup(?)
.text:00001200 _text           ends
```

На следующем шаге (`objcopy`) из этого исполняемого файла извлекается содержимое **только секции `.text`**, а код загрузчика ядра по факту никак не используется.

Можно убедиться в этом, если с помощью дизассемблера посмотреть содержимое **kernel.bin**, полученного на шаге `objcopy`:

```
seg000:00000000 ; Segment type: Pure code
seg000:00000000 seg000          segment byte public 'CODE' use32
seg000:00000000                 assume cs:seg000
seg000:00000000                 assume es:nothing, ss:nothing, ds:nothing, fs:nothing, gs:nothing
seg000:00000000                 push    ebp
seg000:00000001                 mov     ebp, esp
seg000:00000003                 sub     esp, 10h
seg000:00000006                 mov     dword ptr [ebp-4], 0B8000h
seg000:0000000D                 mov     eax, [ebp-4]
seg000:00000010                 mov     byte ptr [eax], 58h
seg000:00000013                 mov     eax, [ebp-4]
seg000:00000016                 add     eax, 1
seg000:00000019                 mov     byte ptr [eax], 9
seg000:0000001C                 nop
seg000:0000001D                 leave
seg000:0000001E                 retn
seg000:0000001E ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
seg000:0000001F                 align 10h
seg000:0000001F seg000          ends
```

Видим только функцию, без кода ее вызова и бесконечного цикла после вызова.

Нужно сделать, чтобы при линковке все попало в одну секцию. Можно просто явно указать имя секции в **kernelentr.asm**:

```
format elf
use32
extrn _start
section '.text'
call _start

jmp $
```

Результат линковки:

```
.text:00001000 ; Segment type: Pure code
.text:00001000 ; Segment permissions: Read/Execute
.text:00001000 _text           segment dword public 'CODE' use32
.text:00001000                 assume cs:_text
.text:00001000                 ;org 1000h
.text:00001000                 assume es:nothing, ss:nothing, ds:_text, fs:nothing, gs:nothing
.text:00001000
.text:00001000 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:00001000
.text:00001000 ; Attributes: noreturn
.text:00001000
.text:00001000                 public start
.text:00001000 start           proc near
.text:00001000                 call    _start
.text:00001005
.text:00001005 loc_1005:                               ; CODE XREF: start:loc_1005j
.text:00001005                 jmp     short loc_1005
.text:00001005 start           endp
.text:00001005
.text:00001005 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00001007                 align 4
.text:00001008
.text:00001008 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:00001008
.text:00001008 ; Attributes: bp-based frame
.text:00001008
.text:00001008                 public _start
.text:00001008 _start          proc near               ; CODE XREF: startp
.text:00001008
.text:00001008 var_4           = dword ptr -4
.text:00001008
.text:00001008                 push    ebp
.text:00001009                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:0000100B                 sub     esp, 10h
.text:0000100E                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0B8000h
.text:00001015                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
.text:00001018                 mov     byte ptr [eax], 58h
.text:0000101B                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
.text:0000101E                 add     eax, 1
.text:00001021                 mov     byte ptr [eax], 9
.text:00001024                 nop
.text:00001025                 leave
.text:00001026                 retn
.text:00001026 _start          endp
.text:00001026
.text:00001026 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00001027                 align 200h
.text:00001200                 dd 380h dup(?)
.text:00001200 _text           ends
```

Листинг содержимого **kernel.bin**:

```
seg000:00000000                 call    sub_8
seg000:00000005
seg000:00000005 loc_5:                                  ; CODE XREF: seg000:loc_5j
seg000:00000005                 jmp     short loc_5
seg000:00000005 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
seg000:00000007                 align 4
seg000:00000008
seg000:00000008 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
seg000:00000008
seg000:00000008 ; Attributes: bp-based frame
seg000:00000008
seg000:00000008 sub_8           proc near               ; CODE XREF: seg000:00000000p
seg000:00000008
seg000:00000008 var_4           = dword ptr -4
seg000:00000008
seg000:00000008                 push    ebp
seg000:00000009                 mov     ebp, esp
seg000:0000000B                 sub     esp, 10h
seg000:0000000E                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0B8000h
seg000:00000015                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
seg000:00000018                 mov     byte ptr [eax], 58h
seg000:0000001B                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
seg000:0000001E                 add     eax, 1
seg000:00000021                 mov     byte ptr [eax], 9
seg000:00000024                 nop
seg000:00000025                 leave
seg000:00000026                 retn
seg000:00000026 sub_8           endp
```

Дальше проходим по пунктам из вопроса, в конце запускаем **os.bin** с помощью QEMU：

[image: QEMU]

Стабильно показывает X, картинка не меняется (если не считать мигающего курсора под Х).

Comment: увы это не помогло(

Comment: @Jiftoo, я полностью прошел по пунктам сборки из вопроса, при запуске работает нормально.

Comment: Я разобрался просто нужно было убрать фуникцию ожидания в биосе которую я не указал в вопросе
`mov al, 0
mov ah, 86h
mov cx, 1
mov dx, 2
int 15h`